# Who's the guy on the front cover of Call of Duty: Black Ops II?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

[image: front cover of Call of Duty: Black Ops II]

See this bald guy? Who is he?

I haven't seen him anywhere in the campaign mode or zombies mode of the game and he doesn't look like any of the multiplayer bot characters, so who is he?

Comment: he IS black ops

Answer (score 0):

His official name is "sitting bull", but nobody knows who it is. It is not Hudson considering he died early on in bo2, well before the B23R that he's holding was made. people are considering the possibility of it being Salazar, but I have no idea personally. Salazar could be possible since his armor matches up fairly well. But it's most likely another generic soldier

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The guy on the cover of black ops 2 is Hudson.

Comment: How do you know? Can you provide more information on where this is said in the game or some other source?